# Adding A JOIN To A MySQL Query Is Throwing Strange Error

Tags: php, mysql, performance, stored-procedures, join

I am creating a MySQL PROCEDURE. The tables and their data were provided by MAXMIND's location IP services and can be found [here](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing). The PROCEDURE was not created by me, but it works exactly for what I need except I am trying to add a JOIN to the query. I am trying to take the id of the "destination" and query the photos table to grab the photos.

**The Tables**

```
|   locations    ||     photos     |
|________________||________________|
 |              |  |              | 
 |      id      |  |     id       |  
 |   latitude   |  |    lid       |
 |   longitude  |  |    pid       |
```

**The Code:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GEODIST`( IN userid int, IN dist int, IN olat float, IN olon float ) DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA

BEGIN
DECLARE mylon DOUBLE;
DECLARE mylat DOUBLE;
DECLARE lon1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lon2 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat2 FLOAT;

SET mylon = olon;
SET mylat = olat;
SET lon1 = mylon - dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lon2 = mylon + dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lat1 = mylat - ( dist / 69 );
SET lat2 = mylat + ( dist / 69 );

SELECT destination.id, destination.latitude, destination.longitude, photos.lid,
photos.pid, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -destination.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(destination.latitude * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -destination.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance 
FROM locations destination, locations origin JOIN photos ON photos.lid = destination.id WHERE origin.id = userid
AND destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2 
HAVING distance < dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50;
END
```

The problem is, when I make the call to the PROCEDURE, I receive the following error:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'destination.id' in 'on clause'
```

Without the JOIN clause in the query, everything works just fine. The query properly works, so I know that it has to do with the JOIN, but I can not figure out what is going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Redo my comment - what is the relation between locations destination and locations origin?  Cross join?

Comment: @Twelfth It's a deliberate CROSS JOIN (a cross self join), so you get all combinations of origin and destination to get the distance between all locations ... and then filter out those combinations wanted.

Comment: @VMai Thats what I suspected...was confirming since he was mixing join syntax there.  Heh, you beat me to the answer by not confirming and just answering :)

Comment: Either ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operator and use the `JOIN` keyword, -or- move the join predicates to the `WHERE` clause. Don't mix the old-school comma syntax and the `JOIN .. ON` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't mix the comma operator and explicit joins as you do:

```
...
FROM locations destination, locations origin JOIN photos ON photos.lid = destination.id
...
```

You should use CROSS JOIN instead:

```
FROM locations destination CROSS JOIN locations origin JOIN photos ON photos.lid = destination.id
```

The manual chapter [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) explains this:

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I am looking to grab all of the destinations, and then grab all of the photos associated with those destinations, maybe I did something wrong here, but the query actually ran this time which is a big step forward, but it only provided me with the destinations that had photos, it did not provide me with any destinations without any listings in the photos table. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: It is supplying the same result and duplicating as many times as there are photos: ex, if location1 has 5 photos, then there are 5 location1's in the result, but if there is no photos for location2, then location2 is not in the results list at all.

Comment: @mcbeav To get locations without photos use a left join. To get only one row for each location instead of a row per photo you can add a `GROUP BY destination.id` clause and use the aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT on your photo columns. By the way the performance will be even worse. Maybe you should explore this in a new question. Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: That is interesting to know. Thank you for the information and I appreciate it. I will see what I can do with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is your `from` clause:

```
FROM locations destination,
     locations origin JOIN
     photos
     ON photos.lid = destination.id
WHERE origin.id = userid AND
      destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND
      destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2
```

You are mixing implicit and explicit joins.  This is a bad idea, and now you know at least one reason why.  You get strange errors.  A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

You can fix this by replacing the `,` with `cross join`:

```
FROM locations destination CROSS JOIN
     locations origin JOIN
     photos
     ON photos.lid = destination.id
WHERE origin.id = userid AND
      destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND
      destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2
```

`CROSS JOIN` is almost exactly the same as the comma.  Except, the columns in the first table are known to the rest of the `from` clause.  However, you should really fix the `join`s.  This is a guess:

```
FROM photos JOIN
     locations destination
     ON photos.lid = destination.id JOIN
     locations origin
     ON origin.id = userid
WHERE destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND
      destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2
```

Comment: This is great information. I am going to give this a go, I am not well versed in MySQL, and am still learning. This is all new to me. Thanks for your help. I am going to try this and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I am looking to grab all of the destinations, and then grab all of the photos associated with those destinations, maybe I did something wrong here, but the query actually ran this time which is a big step forward, but it only provided me with the destinations that had photos, it did not provide me with any destinations without any listings in the photos table. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I tried using the cross join exactly as suggested in the first chunk of code.

Comment: I just tried changing the code to the botom portion of the code you supplied, and it seems that I am getting the same result. It is supplying the same result and duplicating as many times as there are photos: ex, if location1 has 5 photos, then there are 5 location1's in the result, but if there is no photos for location2, then location2 is not in the results list at all.

Comment: @mcbeav . . . The logic in your original query is simply not correct.  However, your question was about the syntax problem, not the logic.  I would suggest that you ask another question and include sample data and desired results.